# System LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001

Tags: schedulebatch

I am writing a batch class in which I am getting too many query rows : 50001 error.I am pasting the execute method code, please let me know the error I am making.The error I am getting is on the **emailmessage** list.

```
global class LC_CreateArchivedEmailMessagesBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{

  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
  {
     String query='Select id,LastModifiedDate,ParentId,RecordTypeId,IsClosed FROM Case WHERE LastModifiedDate <= : D1 AND ParentId != Null AND IsClosed = true LIMIT 50000 ';
     return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
  }  
  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject>scope)

  {  
     Date D = System.Today().AddMonths(-18);
        system.debug('D-->'+D); 
           Map<String,String> mapRecordTypeIdName=new  Map<String,String>();
     Map<String,String> mapRecordTypeNameID=new  Map<String,String>();
     Schema.sObjectType objType = Case.getSObjectType();
     Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sObjReslt = objType.getDescribe();  
     Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapByName = sObjReslt.getRecordTypeInfosByName();

     for(String str:rtMapByName.keySet())
         {
              Schema.RecordTypeInfo rtByName =  rtMapByName.get(str);
             if(rtByName.isAvailable()){
                 System.debug('RecordTypeName--->'+rtByName.getName());
             if(rtByName.getName()=='Operations' || rtByName.getName()=='Operations - AA' || rtByName.getName() == 'Operations - Account Inquiry' || rtByName.getName() == 'Operations - CAO'
                || rtByName.getName() == 'Operations - IR'){   
                 mapRecordTypeIdName.put(rtByName.getRecordTypeId(),rtByName.getName());
                 mapRecordTypeNameID.put(rtByName.getName(),rtByName.getRecordTypeId());
               }
             }  
         }

         Map<id,Case> em = new Map<id,Case>([Select id,LastModifiedDate,ParentId,RecordTypeId,IsClosed FROM 
                                            Case WHERE LastModifiedDate <= : D AND ParentId != Null and (RecordTypeId =:mapRecordTypeNameID.get('Operations')
                                            OR RecordTypeId =:mapRecordTypeNameID.get('Operations - AA') OR RecordTypeId =:mapRecordTypeNameID.get('Operations - Account Inquiry')
                                            OR RecordTypeId =:mapRecordTypeNameID.get('Operations - CAO') OR RecordTypeId =:mapRecordTypeNameID.get('Operations - IR'))
                                            AND IsClosed = true]);
         system.debug('em-->'+em);
         system.debug('em-->'+em.size());


         List<EmailMessage> emailmessage = new List<EmailMessage>();
         emailmessage =  [SELECT ActivityId,BccAddress,CcAddress,
                          CreatedById,CreatedBy.Name,CreatedDate,FromAddress,FromName,HasAttachment,
                          Headers,Id,Incoming,IsDeleted,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedBy.Name,LastModifiedDate,MessageDate,
                          ParentId,ReplyToEmailMessageId,Status,Subject,ToAddress 
                          FROM EmailMessage WHERE ParentId IN: em.keyset() LIMIT 40000]; 

         system.debug('emailmessagesize -->'+emailmessage.size());
 }
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
```

Comment: Please post the entire batch code

Comment: @d_k Edited the code and pasted the whole batch!

Comment: What's the scope of batch?

Comment: Could you post how much   system.debug('em-->'+em.size());  is and also 

 system.debug('emailmessagesize -->'+emailmessage.size()); ?

If their sum is higher than 50k you've got your answer ;)

Thanks.

Comment: looks like error is because of SOQL in map EM.Get the size of the map in debug

Answer (score 0):

You can try below ideas :-

1. Reduce the batch size. The will reduce the number of Case that appear in the execute scope.. 
   See 
   Database.executeBatch(Object, integer)
   [enter link description here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_executeBatch_2)
   .
2. Modify your SOQL queries to be more selective and to only bring back the records required for the Case in the scope. If possible you could modify the query more specific. The typical approach here is to create a Set of caseIds to use in the SOQL where clauses.
3. you have modify your query in start method , beacure what i can see you didn't use the record which you have get from your Scope.

If you take the batch size all the way down to one then you could just use COUNT() in some cases.